# Returning only Last value in SQLite Select Statement

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

Here i am trying to get all the data from the table in SQLite. But every time its returning   me only last rows twice(my table contains two rows only).

```
e.g
---------------------+
| Id| name | mobile  |                  
|--------------------|
|1  | abc  | 123456  |
|--------------------|
|2  | xyz  | 789654  |
+--------------------+
```

My code returning this:

```
01-11 00:14:59.291: D/Result:(27629): TID 12274, Name: Tablets , Image: [B@4275d578
01-11 00:14:59.291: D/Result:(27629): TID 12274, Name: Tablets , Image: [B@4275d578
```

Here I am pasting my query code:

```
public List<ProductCategoryDatabaseRetrieve> getProductCategoryData() {
    List<ProductCategoryDatabaseRetrieve> productCategoryDatabaseRetrieve = new ArrayList<ProductCategoryDatabaseRetrieve>();
    ProductCategoryDatabaseRetrieve prodCatDB = new ProductCategoryDatabaseRetrieve();
    SQLiteDatabase sqliteDB = dbHandler.getWritableDatabase();
    String[] columns = { DatabaseHandler._TID,
            DatabaseHandler.TID,
            DatabaseHandler.PRODUCT_CATEGORY_NAME,
            DatabaseHandler.PRODUCT_CATEGORY_IMAGE };
    Cursor cursor = sqliteDB.query(DatabaseHandler.PRODUCT_CATEGORY_TABLE,
            columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor.getCount() > 0 && cursor !=null) {
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            prodCatDB.set_tid(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHandler._TID)));
            prodCatDB.setTid(String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(DatabaseHandler.TID))));
            prodCatDB.setProductCategoryName(cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(DatabaseHandler.PRODUCT_CATEGORY_NAME)));
            prodCatDB.setProductCategoryImage(cursor.getBlob(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(DatabaseHandler.PRODUCT_CATEGORY_IMAGE)));
            productCategoryDatabaseRetrieve.add(prodCatDB);
    }
    } 
    dbHandler.close();
    return productCategoryDatabaseRetrieve;
}
```

Thank a lot for considering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you are instantiating `ProductCategoryDatabaseRetrieve prodCatDB = new ProductCategoryDatabaseRetrieve();` outside of the `while` loop once and then replacing it's property values with each loop iteration.


Move `ProductCategoryDatabaseRetrieve prodCatDB = new ProductCategoryDatabaseRetrieve();` to inside the `while` loop like

```
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        ProductCategoryDatabaseRetrieve prodCatDB = new ProductCategoryDatabaseRetrieve();//Instantiate here with each iteration.
        prodCatDB.set_tid(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHandler._TID)));
        prodCatDB.setTid(String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(DatabaseHandler.TID))));
        prodCatDB.setProductCategoryName(cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(DatabaseHandler.PRODUCT_CATEGORY_NAME)));
        prodCatDB.setProductCategoryImage(cursor.getBlob(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(DatabaseHandler.PRODUCT_CATEGORY_IMAGE)));
        productCategoryDatabaseRetrieve.add(prodCatDB);
}
```

Also, in your `if` statement, `cursor != null` is useless. The cursor will never be null, and even if it is `cursor.getCount()` will throw an null pointer exception before `cursor != null` is reached. Remove `cursor != null`, you don't need it.